# R package, size of dataset vis-a-vis code

Tags: r, dataset, package

I am designing an **R** package (http://github.com/bquast/decompr) to run the Wang-Wei-Zhu export decomposition (http://www.nber.org/papers/w19677).

The complete package is only about 79 kilobyte.

I want to supply an example dataset especially because the input objects are somewhat complex. A relevant real world dataset is available from http://www.wiod.org, however, the total size of the .Rdata object would come to about 1 megabyte.

My question therefore is, would it be a good idea to include the relevant dataset that is so much larger than the package itself?

Answer (score 1):

It is not usual for code to be significantly smaller than data. However, I will not be the only one to suggest the following (especially if you want to submit to CRAN):

- Consult the [R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages) manual. In particular, make sure that the data file is in a compressed format and use `LazyData` when applicable.
- The [CRAN Repository Policies](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) also have a thing or two to say about data files. There is a hard maximum of 5MB for documentation and data. If the code is likely to change and the data are not, consider creating a separate data package.
- [PDF documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Writing-package-vignettes) can also be distributed, so it is possible to write a "vignette" that is not built by running code when the package is bundled, but instead illustrates usage with static code snippets that show how to download the data. Downloading in the vignette itself is prohibited, as the manual states that all files necessary to build it must be available on the local file system.

I also would have to ask if including a subset of the data is not sufficient to illustrate the use of the package.

Finally, if you don't intend to submit to a package repository, I can't imagine a megabyte download being a breach of etiquette.

Comment: thanks, I would include a subset of the data, but IO tables are such that row and column sum to the same amounts, which makes cutting out a part problematic